# A problem related to libmkl_tbb_thread.so sth when installing kaldi

Tags: ubuntu

everyone.When I tried to install KALDI on TSUBAME,I faced a failure that says ***configure failed: /usr/apps.sp3/isv/intel/xe2013.1.046/composer_xe_2013_sp1.2.144/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_tbb_thread.so not found. ***
Do I need to find a libmkl_tbb_thread.so file and paste it into /usr/... dir?But I didn't find any website to download libmkl_tbb_thread.so.
Please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Which platforms has Kaldi been compiled on?

We have compiled Kaldi on Windows, Cygwin, various flavors of Linux (including Ubuntu, CentOS, Debian, Red Hat and SUSE), and Darwin. We recommend you use g++ version 4.4 or above, although other compilers such as llvm and Intel's icc are also known to work.

Please see...
http://kaldi.sourceforge.net/build_setup.html